# Cordova giving strange error on building for android

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk

I have latest Cordova installed with crosswalk plugin. I am trying to figure out an issue for many days.
The issue is when I build I get the following error

```
After much discussion and analysis of the market, we have decided to discontinue support for Android 4.0 (ICS) in Crosswalk starting with version 20.
```

I have latest `android` versions installed with the SDK. For more info see the following snapshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNRaY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats NOT a ERROR, its just a INFO given by Crosswalk plugin that they have discontinued the support for Android 4.0. You need to see the full stacktrace for your actual ERROR.